# JMeter Reference a variable when using random file from folder message source

Tags: variables, jmeter

Im using JMS Publisher with Message source -> Random File from folder.
In the message source text files, I want to reference a generated variable.
Is this possible when using random file message source. I can get it to work when using textarea message source by just using ${varName} but this does not seem to work when using random file from folder.